Robot_pose_ekf not publishing transformation of odom_combined frame
I am using the ROS melodic and trying to fuse the odom and IMU using robot_pose_ekf package
Here is my code
    <node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf">
  <remap from="odom" to="mobile_base_controller/odom"/>
  <remap from="imu_data" to="imu"/>
  <param name="output_frame" value="odom_combined"/>
  <param name="base_footprint_frame" value="base_link"/>
  <param name="freq" value="30.0"/>
  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0"/>
  <param name="odom_used" value="true"/>
  <param name="imu_used" value="true"/>
  <param name="vo_used" value="false"/>
  <param name="debug" value="false"/>
  <param name="self_diagnose" value="false"/>
</node>

It gives me the data on the /robot_pose_e/odom_combined topic
    ---
header: 
  seq: 106
  stamp: 
    secs: 1717573637
    nsecs:  84619338
  frame_id: "odom_combined"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -0.399364862348
      y: -0.219302699177
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0170796915986
      y: -0.0205961321005
      z: 0.463817897285
      w: 0.885526420631
  covariance: [3.0992086976766586e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0992086976766586e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 107000000.000001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.74790532886982e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.74790532886982e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.151972562912325e-06]
---

But it does not publish the tf of the odom_combined frame.
How can I Get the transformation of odom_combined frame?
